# How can I publish to a 64 bit target from a 32 bit machine?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, publish

My dev machine is 32 bit, and my target is a 64 bit web server. I normally just avoid overwriting the 64 bit SQLite assemblies on the web server, but I would like to be able to agnostically just always build and publish, and have the choice of assemblies taken care of behind the scenes. How do I go about this?

Comment: Does [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042453/how-to-cross-compile-64bit-dll-with-vs-2005-on-32bit-computer) help at all? You seem to be asking for a cross-compile from 32-bit VS to 64-bit, which requires the right configuration settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid platform specific issues, "Any CPU" as your target will make sure that your binary will run fine on both platforms.

Keep in mind that those binaries built on 32-bit systems will run using the WOW64 emulation layer on 64-bit systems.

Probably the document [64-bit Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx) will cover your question.

Comment: thanks, but it's not the binaries I build I'm worried about, but those I use and build against. I have to code against 32 bit SQLite e.g., but deploy with 64 bit. I'd like to do a '64 bit build' when I publish instead of manually replacing the assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

multiple build configurations in Visual Studio will let you do this to target for x86 and x64  ....